# What are the advantages of using SQLite (or any DBMS) over XML for a desktop application's configuration data?

Tags: xml, database, sqlite

What are the advantages of using SQLite (or any DBMS) over XML for a desktop application's configuration data? 
The configuration data shall be read once when the application is initialized and shall not be modified by application. The data may be manually modified once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is used as one of the ways of storing data. one of using xml is, it makes the data easy to be readable. you can use mysql if there are lot of users need the access to the data at the same time and mysql also supports transactional processing of data whereas xml does not have such features.

I have answered this as the question against MySQL.

[Benefits or using XML over MySQL and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639565/benefits-or-using-xml-over-mysql-and-vice-versa/4639587#4639587)

Answer (score 0):

don't see an advantage at all, especially if the data is not modified by the application, and it must all be read at once when the application initializes.  Are you in a bizarre situation where you have SQLite available, but no XML parser?